# Can I approximate an electron beam in the air to a Gaussian beam?

Tags: electrons, structural-beam

We have used an electron beam (with energy of 6 MeV, used for treatment of cancer patients) and calculated the received dosage. The experiment was set up with a stationary sensor at length approximately 3.8 m away from the beam source. Beam opening was 40 x 40 cm and it was calibrated to receive a dosage of 400 Gy per minute. At intervals of 5° we have moved the beam away from the sensor and recorded the received dosage. I have normalized the dosage and have tried to make a Gaussian beam approximation, but have received a somewhat incorrect result - the slope of the Gaussian is not steep enough. I am wondering if this approximation is even possible to make or how to improve the accuracy of the estimation. Figure bellow (blue are experimental results, red dots are approximations).

[image: I/Imax vs degress]

Comment: This post references particle beams with Gaussian profiles. [Cross-sectional area of a Gaussian beam of particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543229/37364)

Comment: Perhaps you might find something in [Laser and Particle Beams](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/lpb/)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, will check it out!

Comment: seems like you measured your own beam profile, doesn't it?

Comment: Check your data's (excess) kurtosis. A Gaussian has 0. A non-zero result will tell you how far from Gaussian you are, and then go from there.